# Web service's URL works fine with "/" but not with "%2F"

Tags: php, json, web-services, url, urlencode

I'm facing a strange behaviour while working with a web-service.

Most of the URLs send me back a correct json response even if I work with `urlencode()`.

So, for example, if I use http://mywebservice/?q=json_themes_abc%2F254 or http://mywebservice/?q=json_themes_abc/254, I'll get the same response.

But, only for one type of request, http://mywebservice/?q=json_demarches/2808 works and not http://mywebservice/?q=json_demarches%2F2808.

It happens only with `?q=json_demarches` requests.

Does someone have a clue? Is the problem in my side or their? I read something about turning on “AllowEncodedSlashes” directive in their Apache but wouldn't be a general issue with all their URL if so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two forms of the URLs are different and should mean different things. In theory, only one of them should be recognized by the service. And of course what the service does with the URLs it gets is completely its own business.

Comment: The fact is that I know the guy behind the webservice. So I can warn him if I see something wrong. Are you telling me that the problem is probably in his side?